# Wifi Device don't get conneced to a network

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a 802.11 n WiFi device. It connects to a network when connected to another PC. But when I connect to my PC it does not connect to the same network. Does anyone have a solution? I am using windows 10.

Comment: Your PC I think does not have the updated drivers for the network adapter. Ask its manufacturer or visit their website

Comment: The problem is that it connects to all other networks. It has problem with one network and connecting to that network from my pc.